# Stack-snippets editor vs standard editor

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets, editor

When asking/answering questions there is often an issue when indenting code thats not necessarily runnable in the standard editor. Pressing the tab key simply tabs to the next control on the form.

This leads to posters often creating a stack-snippet simply for ease of indentation when asking a question even if the code is not intended to run, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386412/alfresco-aikau-debugging) for example asks a question providing a code snippet that's not intended to be runnable within a browser.

While I don't necessarily see this as a bad thing as it promotes proper formatting and easier reading for those who take time to answer its also an additional step for those who want to answer a question quickly with a formatted example.

---

### Overall question

I guess in a nutshell I'm asking if we should either incorporate the idea of easy indentation in the standard editor or allow a user to specify (in their code snippet) that they don't want to run their snippet in the browser.

Comment: When I saw a bad formatted code in a post, I simply cut and paste it in stack snippet, click on tidy button and then cut and paste it back in the question. Stack snippet will do the job when editing but posting the snippet is very bad idea.

Comment: @sagar V I agree stack snippets is a great tool for formatting code but I feel like it's just extra steps to achieve the end goal in the standard editor that already formats code. Maybe a code tidy button would be useful in the standard editor?